# Automate running Java EE web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, automation

I want to automate running my Java EE web application, which has a few pages each with forms and a submit button going to the next form etc.

How do I automate running this application? Which tools are good out there?

Comment: You mean you want to automate the form submission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Selenium  web application testing system](http://seleniumhq.org/)